# PHP only returns the first value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

*JQUERY*

When I clicked the both 2 buttons it only returns the value 1

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getvalue = $(".view_btn").val();
    $(".view_btn").click(function() {
        alert(getvalue);
    });
});
```

*PHP*

```
<?php foreach ($studentRankingViewGET as $studentRankingViewSHOW) {?>
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $studentRankingViewSHOW['id'];?>" class="view_btn">
<?php } ?>
```

This returned 2 values .i.e. 1 AND 2

Comment: Share relevant code i.e. where is `.btn` element? and also make it readable. `.val()` will always return value of first element from matched elements. So either iterate them using `.each()` or use DOM relationship to target them

Comment: There is no AJAX code given.... so, what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.view_btn').click(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="123" class="view_btn"/>
   <input type="button" value="456" class="view_btn"/>
```

you should use $(this) as referring object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two buttons with same `class`. You can get the clicked element with [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```js
$(".view_btn").click(function() {
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="view_btn" value="Button 1">Button 1<button>
<button class="view_btn" value="Button 2">Button 2<button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will support for dynamic content also

```js
$(".view_btn").on("click", function() {
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="view_btn" value="Button 1">Button 1<button>
<button class="view_btn" value="Button 2">Button 2<button>
```